# Django: Is there a safe and robust way to allow account-holders to have separate domains on your app?

Tags: django, web-applications, multiple-domains

If I want my account holders to be able to have their own sub-domains and even their own domains altogether. Using NGINX as my proxy server, should I create domains for each one in my NGINX conf and have my clients point their domains there or is there reasons why this would be bad? Also, if I do that, how can I pass account-specific (account in Django DB) information in with the request (ie, request from www.spamfoosaccount.com to my server, so I proxy the request back to Apache, but how does my application know that it came from spamfoo's account unless I look at request.HTTP_HOST (which might be the best way, but I don't know until I ask). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know from which domain a request is coming from, you have to use `request.META["HTTP_HOST"]`.

However, do not rely on this value for authentication, it can be forged easily. Authentication should be done in the usual way with `django.contrib.session`. A request from a specific domain/subdomain should not have more privileges/rights, even when the request contains an authenticated session. Privileges should be given to users/groups of users, not to domains.

Note that browser sessions cannot cross second-level-domains (e.g. session cookie from foo.com wil not be sent to bar.com), it can however be a *.foo.com cookie for all subdomains (if you explicitly set it so).

Let your users point their DNS records to the IP of your server, let NGINX route the request based on the domain to your backend and do normal authentication in Django.

Your question:

> how does my application know that it
>   came from spamfoo's account

I don't know the specifics of your application, but it shouldn't matter where the request came from, but who issued the request (e.g. an  authenticated user). You should have a model/field that links your users to their respective domains. When a user is linked to only one domain, the application should assume the user came from that domain. When a user is connected to more than one domain, you can look at `request.META["HTTP_HOST"]`. If this value matches any of the domains, the user is linked to, it's alright, the value may be forged, but by a user that is linked to that domain nonetheless.